# How to add multiple buttons to a NavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Ok, so I've successfully added a rightBarButtonItem to call a custom selector (called from a UIViewController), as follows:

```
 UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

 [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showInfoView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:infoButton];
```

Is it possible to make the "right bar button item" actually be several distinct buttons (and thus remove the title text from the navigation bar)?

I'm searching for ways to get more screen real estate, and this seems like a logical choice... although any other suggestions would be appreciated (maybe i should reduce the size of the tab bar i use at the bottom...)

Answer (score 21):

```
UIBarButtonItem *addAcc = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Add"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(addNewAcc)];

UIBarButtonItem *delAcc = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
          initWithTitle:@"Del"                                            
          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
          target:self 
          action:@selector(DeleteButtonAction)];

NSArray *arrBtns = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:addAcc,delAcc, nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = arrBtns;
```

Comment: That generates an warning...incompatible pointer conversion assigning UIBarButtonItem * from an NSArray *_strong..

Comment: @JayprakashDubey, I'm assuming you accidentally left the 's' off of '.rightBarButtonItems' on the last line which generates your error. Hope you got it to work anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use a `UISegmentedControl` with the bar style.  Or you could add a generic `UIView` and add whatever buttons you want.

Comment: @Matt is correct UISegmented Control is not for that purpose and you should read the UIDesign Reference Guidelines from Apple First. Thanks

Comment: To be fair, their design reference was different when this answer was posted.