# How can I edit a manually added UINavigationBar sub view in interface builder using storyboards?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I've added a UIView as a sub view of a navigation bar and resized it to look like a tool bar.

**It will house 3 buttons:**

- One for changing the style of how clothing items in a collection view
- One for filtering results e.g. favourites, recommended etc
- One for refining results

I'd prefer to create these buttons and doing all the editing in interface builder. Is this possible?

**Here is my current code I use to create the view:**

```
@interface MyCollectionViewController () <UIScrollViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) UIView *filterBar;

@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIView *filterBar = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 42, self.view.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height)];

    [[[self navigationController] navigationBar] addSubview:filterBar];
    [filterBar setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.9f]];
    [filterBar setTag:1];
}
```

My buttons will be like select buttons that trigger UIActionSheet instances or push other controllers onto the top of the stack where I can provide an interface for carrying out an action e.g. refining types of clothes then searching.

**Here is a photo of the an app with the bar I'm talking about:**

[image]

Anyway the is this possible, can I link the view I created in code above up in interface builder and work on it visually rather than in code?

Thanks for your time.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't really...

Storyboards/IB don't allow much customization of UINavigationBar aside from setting title and left/right barButtonItems. Most of what (it seems like) you want to do has to be done in code using a custom UIView subclass.

Longer answer:

To use the standard UINavigationBar, your menu, search, star & suitcase(?) icons at the top would need to be added as arrays of barButtonItems set to the left & right sides. This can only be done in code (you *could* use a segmented control but need to customize appearance in code anyway).
See 2nd response here for an example: [How to add multiple buttons to a NavigationBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413126/how-to-add-multiple-buttons-to-a-navigationbar?rq=1)

For the 2nd "filter" row, looks like it would have to be a separate view created & added separately as you've already done, but ideally an instance of a custom UIView subclass. You can't expand/add that many things to the navigation bar in IB.

Create a new UIView subclass. Then in IB drag out/resize a UIview and set it to be your custom class. You could then drag out items to sort of approximate your design. 
The issue is that IB only has stock UIKit items and options for customizing them can be limited.

- The collection view toggle *could* be a segmented control, but you
  can only change/remove the default blue-rounded border in code, so
  you're not saving any work.
- Your middle "filter" dropdown would have to be a UIPickerView
  (spinner), or perhaps a UITableView subclass. Either of these you'd
  have to code a bunch of separately anyway.
- The right-side "refine" button could be just a simple UIButton w/a
  label. You'd have to change the default color & add a border in code or w/a custom image anyway (since iOS7 removed button borders).

You really might as well code it. IB isn't going to save much time or energy for this many custom elements...

Comment: I eventually saw it was too much hassle and decided to do it in code. Wasn't as difficult as I thought it would be.

Comment: Cool - good question though, and the design looks nice. Gave me a chance to think about how I might do it myself... ~cheers

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, you can drag a UIView to a UINavigationItem in a UINavigationBar:

[image: Storyboard]

This view you just dragged is accessible as:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView
```

You can also link the buttons or whatever you put in that view to your .m file